# Is Two phase commit possible using RMI and Spring

Tags: spring, transactions, websphere, rmi, distributed

I need to know if spring transaction manager allows Two Phase Commit.
We are going to use IBM Websphere as the server. And technology would be spring.

Our requirement is as follows.
One application (A) will call other application(B) on other server using RMI,  and update the database using application (B). Once the RMI response is received other application (C) will be invoked using RMI and database is updated using (C). If the C application fails i need the Transaction at both B & C to be rollbacked.

Plase help.